# Creating a running Time separate from the System's Time

Tags: java, android, clock, android-timer

I want to disregard the Device Time and want to implement my own Clock inside my app. The time I need will be coming from the server.

I have already set its Date and Time as follow:

```
Date.setDate()
```

and

```
Date.setTime()
```

Now, I just need to get my private Date running like a clock.

How can I do this?

EDIT:
So far, I have not implemented anything as I have no idea on how to create a clock/timer starting on a specific date/time object. I am thinking of having a thread and a runnable for ticking but I don't know how to increment it to make it work just like a clock.

Comment: please elaborate " I just need to get my private Date running like a clock"

Comment: easiest way is to just remember the difference between device time and your desired time.
whenever you need time, just add the difference to the device time.

Comment: As for Pooya's question, I have declared a Date Object inside my class and assigned a new value to it. I need to have a clock running based on that newly assigned Date object.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please
[edit] your question to show the code you have written so
far and where you are stuck, then we can try to help with
specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I apologise but I haven't tried anything yet as I have no idea on how to implement it. Sorry :(

Comment: Try mahe's suggestion to keep track of the private time easily.